# Run Java 12 application in Docker

Tags: java, docker, java-12

I took a look at [OpenJDK](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk) Docker repository and found no JRE image for Java 12. There is one for Java 11 (`openjdk:11.0.2-jre`), but for 12 there are only JDK images.

**Q:** How to use OpenJDK JRE 12 to run an application in Docker without using a full JDK image?

Comment: As of 2023, Java 12 has been end of life for 4 years.  If readers are still using or trying to use it, they are potentially putting themselves at risk!  You would be advised to use one of the LTS releases of Java; i.e. Java 8, 11, 17 or 21.  The non-LTS releases only have a lifetime of 6 months: this applies to >>ALL<< vendors, as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk12&jvmVariant=hotspot) is already providing Java 12 JRE [docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk12) (`adoptopenjdk/openjdk12:jre-12.33`)

AdoptOpenJDK is a Java community based effort and from its [about page](https://adoptopenjdk.net/about.html):

> AdoptOpenJDK.net started in 2017 following years of discussions about
>   the general lack of an open and reproducible build & test system for
>   OpenJDK source across multiple platforms.

And one key point of their mission is:

> Provide a reliable source of OpenJDK binaries for all platforms, for the long term future!

There is no pull request for `12 jre` on [OpenJdk official image repository](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk) yet (which is maintained by Docker community.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully deploy the following dockerfile for a spring boot application, with gradle and java 12:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk12-openj9 AS TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY build.gradle settings.gradle gradlew $APP_HOME
COPY gradle $APP_HOME/gradle
RUN chmod +x ./gradlew
RUN ./gradlew build || return 0
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x ./gradlew
RUN ./gradlew build -x test

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk12-openj9
ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=example_app-1.0.jar
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE $APP_HOME/build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME .
EXPOSE 8080
#CMD ["java","-jar",$ARTIFACT_NAME]
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dspring.profiles.active=container","-jar","./example_app-1.0.jar"]
```

Comment: To be frank, using Java 12 in 2023 is a bad idea. It was end-of-life in Sept 2019.  In the 4 YEARS since then, there will have been no security patches ... because it is no longer maintained.  At this time you should be using either Java 11 LTS or Java 17 LTS.   Also, be aware that OpenJ9 / Semeru support lifetimes are essentially the same as the Oracle JDK lifetimes (at this time); see https://endoflife.date/ibm-semeru-runtime.